# Wordpress: How to use .htaccess to redirect posts only

Tags: regex, wordpress, .htaccess

I used to have a blog at http://example.com.

Now my blog has moved to http://exampleblog.com and I have something new at http://example.com.

Old blog post links like http://example.com/2017/01/19/hello-world/ now just end up at a 404 page on the new site. The new site wont have any blog posts, so this URL pattern wont exist on the new site.

How do I redirect old URLs like http://example.com/2017/01/19/hello-world/ to http://exampleblog.com/2017/01/19/hello-world/ using .htaccess or a plugin on a global basis? Meaning any blog post url with this pattern will redirect to the new site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up finding this regular expression to use with the [Redirection](https://wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/) plugin:

`\/(\d*)\/(\d*)\/(\d*)\/([A-Za-z0-9-]*)`

Basically I placed that in the Source URL, checked Regular Expression, and then put `http://exampleblog.com/$4` in the Target URL field.